# Pluck together with first using Query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

If I want to get get name of first user in database using eloquent I can do something like that:

```
$user =  User::select('name')->first()->pluck('name');
// or $user =  User::first()->pluck('name');

echo $user;
```

to get only name of this user as string.

However If I try the same using only query builder:

```
$user =  DB::table('users')->select('name')->first()->pluck('name');

echo $user;
```

I get exception:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::pluck()

But without using first it will work:

```
$user =  DB::table('users')->select('name')->where('id',1)->pluck('name');

echo $user;
```

Is it not possible to use `pluck` with `first` using query builder or am I doing something wrong?

PS. Of course I know that I can display any property using `$user->name` without using `pluck` but I'm just curious why using Eloquent it works and using Query Builder it works only when not having both `first` and `pluck`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't want to use `pluck` with `first`, because it's redundant:

```
$query->first() // fetch first row
      ->pluck('name'); // fetch first row again and return only name
```

So use only `pluck`:

```
$query->pluck('name');
```

It does all you need.

---

But there's more.

Under the hood `first` and `pluck` run 2 separate queries, so:

```
$query->where(..)->orderBy(..)->first() // apply where and orderBy
        ->pluck('name'); // no where and orderBy applied here!
```

So it's not only redundant to use `first` before `pluck`, but also it causes unexpected results.

---

You can chain those methods on Eloquent query, since it returns a collection (`get`) or model (`first`), but `Query\Builder` returns just an array (`get`) or `stdObject` (`first`). That's why you couldn't do the same oon the query builder.

Comment: Thanks, again there's not enough documentation on that. I thought it simply get in this case all columns and returns only one or modifies query (when you don't use select) and again returns only this selected column

Comment: Upvoting since this answer is better than mine.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Thanks to `__call` magic methods everywhere calling `pluck` on the Eloquent model proxies the call to the `Eloquent\Builder`, that's why you can do this on the result of `first`. You may not even notice that it just ran another query - and that was the case here.

Comment: Its better the User::select('name')->value('name') option in this case that proposes @Joren

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel 5.1+, you can use the `value` method.

From the docs:

> If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value
>   from a record using the  value method. This method will return the
>   value of the column directly:
>
> ```
> $email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');
> ```

This is how it works behind the scenes in the Builder class:

```
/**
 * Get a single column's value from the first result of a query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return mixed
 */
public function value($column)
{
    $result = (array) $this->first([$column]);
    return count($result) > 0 ? reset($result) : null;
}
```

Comment: Didn't see the laravel-4 tag, thanks! I'll update my answer. It could be useful for others.

Comment: I was getting a mess of different value types until I did the value(). Totally useful. 
$exams = \App\Modules::where('id', $id)->value('exams');
And it returned the ID for the exam I wanted in an simple value type (int or string) and not object or collection. Laravel Framework 5.5.44

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$user =  User::pluck('name')->first();
echo $user;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Current alternative for ***pluck()*** is ***value()***.

To get first occurence, You can either use

```
  DB::table('users')->value('name');
```

or use,

```
 DB::table('users')->pluck('name')->first();
```