# Laravel Query Builder in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

When I use Laravel's query builder for my Lumen application with MySQL database, it does not work as expected. I used:

```
$itemid = DB::table('table1')->where('UserID','=',1)->pluck('ID');
```

This only returns one value. What is the mistake here?

Comment: There's nothing in that code that indicates how many values you should receive back. Going by assumption that `UserID` is unique, then you'll always have 1 record and `pluck` will return 1 record. There's no mistake here whatsoever, the code in Laravel and Lumen is one and the same when it comes to Eloquent / Query builder, so the mistake is in the chair, not in computer.

Comment: How many values do you expect, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use first instead of get as get return array.

**$itemid = DB::table('table1')->where('UserID','=',1)->first()->pluck('ID');**

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$itemid = DB::table('table1')->where('UserID','=',1)->get()->pluck('ID');
```

Here you can read more about why this happen when you use pluck on query 
[Pluck together with first using Query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054354/pluck-together-with-first-using-query-builder)

Update:
I forget that DB::table returns array, so:

```
$items = DB::table('table1')->where('UserID','=',1)->get();
$itemsById = array_pluck($items, 'ID');
```

Comment: `Call to a member function pluck() on a non-object` this is the result

Comment: @Geding, since 5.3 it woud return collection. [Look here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10552)