# Want to get data from database in laravel 5.3 as single values but it return with column name

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have started working with laravel 5.3. I want to get data from database but it is not fetching data as I want. For example I have jobs table whitch contain currently 2 records as following.

```
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ id ┃ job        ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1  ┃ Accountant ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 2  ┃ Sales Man  ┃
┗━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

I have created model Named **Job** and have a *jobsController* with the following mathed:

```
public function job(){
    $jobname = Job::select('job')->where('id',2)->get();
    return view('name', array('jobname'=>$jobname));
}
```

And in view it show result like this `[{"job":"Sales Man"}]`. I want result as only **Sales Man**. can somebody tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: nice formate..  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.first` instead of the `.get` so the query returns only one element:

```
$jobname = Job::select('job')->where('id',2)->first();
```

Then you can use `$jobname->job` for reading the attribute.

And here is a related question: [Pluck together with first using Query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054354/pluck-together-with-first-using-query-builder#26054475)

Comment: Greate.. Problem Solved.

Comment: When i use--  return view('jobs', array('jobname'=>$jobname)); -- then the its okay. I saw in a tutorial on youtube, that author used compact($jobname) function instead of array to pass the variable to the page. but when i use the compact function it create an error. can you tell me why. and one other thing that if I want to insert data into jobs table through 1 form field name how can i do tht. will you refer me a simple method because official laravel docomentation is little bit complecated and not suitable for me. waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function job(){

    $jobname = Job::select('job')->where('id',2)->get();
    return view('name', array('jobname'=>$jobname->job));
}
```

you should pass directly the object variable from controller to view....

Comment: ErrorException in jobsController.php line 20:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$job

Comment: is your $jobname an array ?

Comment: you now better. I am a beginner. and only now that my code is givving an output [{"job":"Sales Man"}] and your code gave me error now. which i mentioned above.

Comment: try this return view('name', array('jobname'=>$jobname[0]->job));